# How do I share or forward a network share?

Tags: networking, server, mount, samba

I have a setup where I have a NAS disk that is mounted on the Ubuntu machine and I have hamachi installed on that machine. I need to forward the NAS share so that when I browse the IP of the ubuntu share it will show the share of the NAS. Because in this scenario I cannot install hamachi on the NAS box.

I have the Ubuntu machine and the NAS box on the same network.

I just need to like forward the share. and doing that in the most efficient way possible.

I am on ubuntu 18.04 server

Comment: Can’t the NAS mount point be added to hamachi‘s shared folders?

Comment: Why using hamachi and Not better vpn solutions like wireguard? You can Share using Samba or NFS. U need to share the mount point.

Comment: @AlexOnLinux I need it so I can access my internal NAS from outside my network without port forwarding

Comment: @RyanVogel I know why you are using a VPN ( Virtual Private Network ). You do it, because you want to access your local network from the internet. My question was, why did you choose Hamachi for that. I would suggest you to use a Raspberry Pi with Raspbian Linux installed. As VPN you should choose Wireguard, which works fast, open source, not a chatty protocol and pretty secure software. The Raspberry Pi has almost no power consumption (perhaps 5 Watts, i guess less). Than you have a 24/7 miniserver that allows you to connect ( vpn ) to your local network without any hassel.

Comment: The last time I used Hamachi ist almost 10 years ago, on Windows, to play games with friends that have been almost 20 years old. Nowerdays I wouldn't use that software anymore because it closed source and not necessary to use because of the alternatives: Wireguard, OpenVPN, SSH. And wireguard is pretty easy to setup and has clients for android too.   But apart from the VPN you use, the main point is, that you have to share your mount point via Samba or NFS. Samba is easier to setup for windows and nfs is pretty straight forward for linux clients. **What clients do need access to that share?**

Comment: @AlexOnLinux can you use wire guard without port forwarding?

Comment: The main issue is that I cannot port-forward in this specific situation.

Comment: @RyanVogel You need to forward the port for wireguard to work. There is a way to circumvent it. You need at least one server reachable for all wireguard clients. than the clients can connect to that server and communicate together. To bypass a firewall with wireguard you need to use the KeepAlive 25 command, which sends beacons every 25 seconds to the server. This way the client firewall remains open, so that you can connect to these. As soon as the client goes offline the port will be closed by the firewall too. Next time the client is up, the beacon keeps the firewall port open again

Comment: I have a VPS that is a webserver so if I were to install Wiregaurd on there and set it up on thier and connect all other machines (including NAS machine) it would work>

Comment: Yes that way you can talk to all clients in the wireguard network. As long as they do KeepAlive the connection will remain open and  the firewall will be bypassed. Some further info: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/WireGuard and here the presentation of wireguard from the author if you are interested - for me it was really informative and simple: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F5S4MpTuyoo